# SQLite3 file locking in embedded system

Tags: multithreading, sqlite, locking

There is a special multithreading embedded environment and the SQLite3 engine has to be included and supported there. It requires writing a customized VFS ([`sqlite3_vfs`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/vfs.html)) and customized mutexes ([`sqlite3_mutex_methods`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/mutex_methods.html)). The threading mode is set to *serialized* ([`SQLITE_THREADSAFE=1`](https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#threadsafe)) and the *shared-cache* mode is activated ([`sqlite3_enable_shared_cache`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/enable_shared_cache.html)).

Considering that there are only threads but no processes, **is it necessary to support file locking**?

Answer (score 0):

SQLite uses file locking to prevent multiple connections from interfering with each other.

You need to implement (or emulate) file locking if it is possible to have multiple connections at the same time.
In [shared-cache mode](http://www.sqlite.org/sharedcache.html), multiple connections from the same process actually use a single connection to the database file.

If you do not implement file locking, it would be a good idea to return errors from your `xLock`/`xCheckReservedLock` implementations, and force the application to use a URI filename with the [nolock parameter](http://www.sqlite.org/uri.html#urinolock).

Comment: Multiple simultaneous connections to the same database are definitely required there. However, I supposed that the *shared-cache* mode solves this problem (i.e. it reuses the existing file handle instead of opening another one) without the need of file locking. Is this consideration wrong?